# How to implement stopovers in pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting, distance-matrix, dijkstra

I used to use Dijkstra to find the shortest path between two points. Now I have a shortest route, which uses a street forbidden to use because of internal rules (too slow due to shopping mall).

Now I would like to add a stopover on an alternative road and use a two segments Dijkstra. Is this the best way or should I better work with a turn-restriction network? The latter allows to set the costs for the shortest path / the street in question higher as usual.

The TSP is currently only implemented with Euclidian distance - this is not accurate enough  for European street layouts.

Comment: if it's *forbidden* why not just take it out of the calculation. Dijkstra's algorithm adapts easily to cost/impedance so you could weight this one heavily so that it's only chosen if it's the *only* way to get there; then this would give you an option to light weight preferred paths like better/multi-lane roads, such that even if it's not the shortest path a preferred route will be traversed. Perhaps default each line at 1 (for 1 x length) and go 100 for *forbidden* paths and 0.9 for preferred routes and see how that works out.

Comment: Ok, it is forbidden for the standard route. Nevertheless, it should still be accessible. If I had increased the costs of the edge, I would change the original data and risk increased traveling times in this area. It is possible, but there must be a nicer way keeping the original network untouched...?

Comment: Ok, I made a simple manual select ... where gid in (x,y) inside the routing statement.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 2):

TSP has [2 alternative ways](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/tsp/doc/index.html#pgr-tsp) to be called: one uses the euclidean distance as you said, the second one requires a distance matrix as the first argument:

```
SELECT seq, id FROM pgr_tsp('{{0,1,2,3},{1,0,4,5},{2,4,0,6},{3,5,6,0}}'::float8[],1);

 seq | id
-----+----
   0 |  1
   1 |  2
   2 |  3
   3 |  0
(4 rows)
```

It's up to you how to calculate the distance matrix. If you have many stop points, pgRouting's shortest path functions might not be fast enough.